# HTML: Should I create a section just for a main image?

Tags: html, css

I have a main image at the top of the page. For simplicity working with my stylesheet/layout, I have it in it's own section:

```
<section class="container page-intro boxed-none">

    <figure>
        <img class="width100" src="article-image.png" alt="Template Article" />
    </figure>

</section>
```

When I use the W3C validator, it suggests that a section have a heading. Is it proper markup to have my HTML like this, or should it be modified?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that layout (of course I don't know what's going on around that portion of HTML...)

Comment: It's tough for us to say without knowing how the image relates to the rest of the markup & content on your page and without knowing what the image itself illustrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's suggested that you always use a heading in your `<section>` but if you want you don't have why to use it.
Here is some basic information on how each of the major HTML5 tags can/should be used (I suggest reading the full source linked at the bottom):

> **section** – Used for grouping together thematically-related content.
>   Sounds like a div element, but it’s not. The div has no semantic
>   meaning. Before replacing all your div’s with section elements, always
>   ask yourself: “Is all of the content related?”
>
> **aside** – Used for tangentially related content. Just because some
>   content appears to the left or right of the main content isn’t enough
>   reason to use the aside element. Ask yourself if the content within
>   the aside can be removed without reducing the meaning of the main
>   content. Pullquotes are an example of tangentially related content.
>
> **header** – There is a crucial difference between the header element and
>   the general accepted usage of header (or masthead). There’s usually
>   only one header or ‘masthead’ in a page. In HTML5 you can have as many
>   as you want. The spec defines it as “a group of introductory or
>   navigational aids”. You can use a header in any section on your site.
>   In fact, you probably should use a header within most of your
>   sections. The spec describes the section element as “a thematic
>   grouping of content, typically with a heading.”
>
> **nav** – Intended for major navigation information. A group of links
>   grouped together isn’t enough reason to use the nav element. Site-wide
>   navigation, on the other hand belongs in a nav element.
>
> **footer** – Sounds like its a description of the position, but its not.
>   Footer elements contain informations about its containing element: who
>   wrote it, copyright, links to related content, etc. Whereas we usually
>   have one footer for an entire document, HTML5 allows us to also have
>   footer within sections.
>
> **Source:**
>   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp